# Black Screen RDP to Azure VM following Group Policy Updates

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, rdp, group-policy

I am unable to access my Windows VMs through RDP. The authentication is fine, but when the window appears the desktop is black, with nothing appearing at all. I am connecting via the MacOS desktop app through a VPN.

I've tried the following with the same outcome:

- Connecting a Windows machine outside of the VPN
- Connecting via Bastion
- Display setting adjustments, e.g. reducing to 640x480, 16-bit colour, etc.
- Restarting the VM

It has started today following recommended security updates to Group Policy on the VMs in question, such as the recommended *Ensure 'Do not allow passwords to be saved' is set to 'Enabled'*, and *Ensure 'Always prompt for password upon connection' is set to 'Enabled'*, which are part of the Defender for Cloud 'Machines should be configured securely' security posture guidance.

I cannot connect to the machines to undo these changes.

RDP sessions to non-Azure resources are fine.

Comment: From inspection of the WAC logs, it's the dwm.exe process that's crashing every time RDP is connected. This is happening for 5 VMs today.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same issue in my environment and got the below results***

*- This issue will be over screen resolution or slow  internet
connection or client connectivity*

*- *Click on black RDP window and press CTRL+ALT+END then click on LOG OFF and login again it will connect the remote windows VM**

*I have created the VM and connected the virtual machine through RDP*

[image]

*Connected the windows VM outside of the VPN*
*We have to configure the group policy settings on windows VM, To establish the recommended configurations for the Group Policy, please use the below configurations*

*Click on window button and search with* ***local group policy editor*** => ***local computer policy*** => ***computer configuration***

[image]

*In computer configuration's click on* ***administrative templates*** => ***windows components***

[image]

*In windows component click on remote desktop services*

[image]

*In the remote desktop services click on remote desktop client services and check the* ***do not allowed password to be saved*** *or not if not configured we have to enable it*

[image]

*For enabling click on do not allowed password to be saved and click on enable and apply*

[image]

*After enabling the do not allowed password it will be look like below*

[image]

***NOTE:***
*If the policy settings was previously configured as disabled or not configured and any previously saved passwords will be deleted then the  remote desktop will will be disconnected from the server.*